# Can't read root

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

So I'm using SharpSVN(SharpSvn.1.7-x86 1.7008.2243) and I keep running into a problem. Every time I try to use the `SvnWorkingCopyClient` on a repo that's at the root of a drive( for example say I have the `D:\` drive, and it itself is a repo) it throws a `svn_dirent_is_absolute` error at me.

In fact the only command I could find that didn't care was `SvnClient.GetUriFromWorkingCopy(string)`

Any Ideas on how I could resolve this(aside from moving my working copy, or linking on the filesystem)? I'm hoping to find a way in code, or an alternative to work around this limitation(as it appears that SVN 1.7 doesn't have this limitation anymore).

Here's some code?

```
private void fakeFunction(){
    var RootPath="d:\";
    using (var client = new SharpSvn.SvnClient())
    using(var workingClient = new SvnWorkingCopyClient())
    {
        SvnWorkingCopyVersion workingVersion = null;
        // Exception happens here
        if (workingClient.GetVersion(this.RootPath, out workingVersion))
        {
            CurrentRevision = workingVersion.End;
                // This will resolve just fine
            var targetUri = client.GetUriFromWorkingCopy(RootPath);
            var target = SvnTarget.FromUri(targetUri);
            SvnInfoEventArgs info = null;
            if (client.GetInfo(target, out info))
            {
                if (workingVersion.End != info.Revision)
                {
                    System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logEventArgs = null;
                    if (client.GetLog(targetUri, out logEventArgs))
                    {
                        var oldBack = Console.BackgroundColor;
                        var oldFor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        foreach (var l in logEventArgs)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("[{0}-{1}]-{2}", l.Revision, l.Author, l.LogMessage);
                        }
                        Console.BackgroundColor = oldBack;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = oldFor;
                    }

                    System.Console.WriteLine("Repo not up to date.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also stumbled across this http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3535 and http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=463&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=2456472

So, since that happened way back when, shouldn't this not be an issue anymore?

Comment: Your second line of code `var RootPath="d:\";` does not compile (is this your actual source?). Also further down you reference `this.RootPath`, that is a different variable, is that what you intend to do?

Comment: Yes. Those are filled at runtime, I was just showing what the path was set to.

Comment: I found the root cause in SharpSvn for this issue. It should be fixed in the next build. It would be much easier for me if you can post this as a small reproducible issue here or on users@sharpsvn.open.collab.net.

Showing workingClient.GetVersion("C:\\", out q) as the problem with the exception output is much easier to diagnose then your full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharSVN has issue with root paths as we can read in mail-archives. However we can made small hack for your occasion:

1. Download full package sharpsvn http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/files/documents/180/5569/SSvnEx-1.7002.1998.zip
2. Copy svnversion.exe to your bin directory
3. Then we need a hack method to get verison

   ```
       public static bool GetVersionHack(string appPath,string targetPath,out long version)
       { 
          // <param name="appPath">Path to svnversion.exe</param>
          // <param name="path">Target path</param>
          // <param name="version">Result version</param>

           Process p = new Process();               

           p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
           p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
           p.StartInfo.FileName = appPath;
           p.StartInfo.Arguments = targetPath + " -n";
           p.Start();

           //read svnversion.exe result
           string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
           p.WaitForExit();

           output = output.Replace("M", "");
           output = output.Replace("S", "");
           output = output.Replace("P", "");

           //valid results
           //4123:4168     mixed revision working copy
           //4168M         modified working copy
           //4123S         switched working copy
           //4123P         partial working copy, from a sparse checkout
           //4123:4168MS   mixed revision, modified, switched working copy            

           return long.TryParse(output, out version);
       }
   ```
4. And modify your fake method [full source code](http://pastebin.com/bMTxk3KA)

Sure its a dirty work around but it can be helpful. Please **be careful** with svnversion.exe results GetVersionHack not ideal.

Comment: This isn't ideal. It would almost make more sense to temporarily copy the whole svn directory to another location, then get the results.

Comment: @kelton52 if you can move it to other location better to do it

Comment: I can't really, and it's a few gig repo...I'm sorry but this solution is too hacky.

Comment: So wait, does version 1.7002.1998 work with root drives? Or is it only that one file?

Answer (score 2):

A kludge is to ".." your way up to the root from your current directory:

```
[pwd = C:\USERS\franklin\absrel]
root = ..\..\..
```

Comment: If this works and can trick it into reading it properly, that I think this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it complains about the absolute path then try defining the unc path instead. Share your D:\ drive which is your svn repo. Then access it using

```
    var RootPath="\\<servername>\D$";
```